# c programming language exercise 3-2 print escape characters in array

Tags: c, switch-statement, escaping

I want to print escape characters like newline and tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t So I think I should print two \ then n to print the visible \n. But it doesn't work. The answer print n then two \ and it works. And I don't know why. Here's my code.

```
case  '\n' :
     s[j] = '\\';
     s[j++] = 'n';
     break;
```

And heres the answer

```
 case '\n':
        s[j++] = '\\';
        s[j] = 'n';
        break;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's all about the `++`.  `j++` means "use the current value of j, then increment it.  So yours does this: `j[0] = '\\'; j[0] = 'n'; j = j + 1`.  You want `s[j] = '\\'; s[++j] = 'n'` (`++j` means increment the value of j *and then* use it)

Comment: Oh thanks! I was wondering and didn't find it out. I don't know how to set comments as answers. Do you mind answer in answers?

Comment: The question is a basic C syntax question and probably isn't going to add value to SO (people might even say the question should be closed for that reason).  Not only would putting in an answer just be rep-mongoring, it might prevent the question being deleted as no adding value. (no offense)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to know the following about increments/decrements:

1. When using them as complete statement (on their own), `i++` and `++i` are equivalent.
2. When using them in an expression, `i++` will use then current value of `i` in the expression and increase `i` **after** the expression has been evaluated whereas `++i` will **first** increase the value of `i`, **then** evaluate the expression.

Therefore:

```
int s[2] = {6,7};
int i = 0;
printf("%d", s[i++]);  //prints 6 then sets i equal to 1
```

Whereas

```
int s[2] = {6,7};
int i = 0;
printf("%d", s[++i]);  //Sets i equal to 1 then prints 7
```

In your case this means that when you use `s[j++]` you are using the same `j` as in the line above before incrementing it (thus overwriting the value of `s[j]` you had just set).